# Determine if MVC view is nested

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, renderaction

I have two MVC views. The parent view uses Html.RenderAction to render a child view.

How, from within the base controller, can I identify whether the current view is an independent view or, whether it being rendered within a parent view using Html.RenderAction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ControllerContext.IsChildAction`. This returns true if RenderAction was used.

```
if (!ControllerContext.IsChildAction) 
{
    // We were called via the URL and not via a [Phil Haack's blog][1]) call.
}
```

See Phil Haack on [MVC2 RenderAction and Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but MVC does have an attribute that allows an action method to be called only as a child action.

[ChildActionOnly Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)